# Stop knitr preamble in looped child .Rnw documents

Tags: r, loops, parent-child, knitr, sweave

I am looping a child `.Rnw` file so I can repeat plots with different species. Unfortunately the preamble for knitr (I think) is being repeated at the beginning of every loop so the `.pdf` will not compile. If I manually remove the repeated preamble in the `.tex` file everything is fine. I have a feeling I am missing some link between parent and child but cannot find where exactly.  I am using R-studio and the files outlined below.

`main.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
some R stuff
@

<<runall, include =FALSE>>=
out<-c()
for(species in c('RH', "GU", "RA", "KI")){
out<- c(out, knit_child('spsummary.Rnw')
}
@

\Sexpr{paste(out, collapse='n')}
\end{document}
```

The child document (`spsummary.Rnw`) is looped over each species:

```
<<>>=
set_parent("main.Rnw")
@

<<>>=
more R stuff
@

\begin{table}
...
\end{table}

\clearpage
\newpage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally answered my own question.

Its a simple case of a missing backslash.

the last but one line of the parent document (main) should read:

```
\Sexpr{paste(out, collapse='\n')}
```

with a backslash before the 'n'

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `set_parent` from your child document, because you do not want to compile the child stand-alone. See this quote from the [help](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/):

> Child documents are often incomplete -- the missing part is the LaTeX
>   preamble as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Sometimes we
>   may want to compile such child documents as if they were complete
>   LaTeX documents. The only one thing we need to do is to extract an 
>   appropriate preamble from a parent document and add it to this child 
>   document. The function `set_parent()` enables this feature; [...] Then 
>   the child document will behave as if it had a preamble

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rolo.  I have tried removing this statement but i still get the preamble in the .tex file for every species (each repeated child).  The preamble that is repeated is all the text colour and error colour things for knitr (not anything I have specified).